# Calculate the amount of consecutive missing values in a row

Tags: python

I am trying to find a way to calculate the amount of values randomly removed from a data frame and the amount of values randomly removed one after another.

The code I have so far is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

#Sampledata
x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1':y,'col_2':x})

drop_indices = np.random.choice(df.index, 5,replace=False )
df_subset = df.drop(drop_indices)

print(df_subset)
print(df)
```

Which randomly removes 5 rows from the data frame and gives as output:

```
  col_1  col_2
0      1      1
1      2      2
2      3      3
5      6      6
8      9      9
   col_1  col_2
0      1      1
1      2      2
2      3      3
3      4      4
4      5      5
5      6      6
6      7      7
7      8      8
8      9      9
9     10     10
```

I would like to turn this into the following data frame:

```
  col_1 col_2 col_2 N_removedvalues   N_consecutive
0     1    1     1    0                 0
1     2    2     2    0                 0
2     3    3     3    0                 0
3     4    4          1                 1
4     5    5          2                 2
5     6    6     6    2                 0
6     7    7          3                 1
7     8    8          4                 2
8     9    9     9    4                 0
9     10   10         5                 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
res=df.merge(df_subset, on='col_1', suffixes=['_1',''], how='left')

res["N_removedvalues"]=np.where(res['col_2'].isna(), res.groupby(res['col_2'].isna()).cumcount().add(1), np.nan)

res["N_removedvalues"]=res["N_removedvalues"].ffill().fillna(0)

res['N_consecutive']=np.logical_and(res['col_2'].isna(), np.logical_or(~res['col_2'].shift().isna(), res.index==res.index[0]))

res.loc[np.logical_and(res['N_consecutive']==0, res['col_2'].isna()), 'N_consecutive']=np.nan

res['N_consecutive']=res.groupby('N_consecutive')['N_consecutive'].cumsum().ffill()

res.loc[res['N_consecutive'].gt(0), 'N_consecutive']=res.loc[res['N_consecutive'].gt(0)].groupby('N_consecutive').cumcount().add(1)
```

Outputs:

```py
   col_1  col_2_1  col_2  N_removedvalues  N_consecutive
0      1        1    1.0              0.0            0.0
1      2        2    2.0              0.0            0.0
2      3        3    NaN              1.0            1.0
3      4        4    4.0              1.0            0.0
4      5        5    NaN              2.0            1.0
5      6        6    NaN              3.0            2.0
6      7        7    7.0              3.0            0.0
7      8        8    8.0              3.0            0.0
8      9        9    NaN              4.0            1.0
9     10       10    NaN              5.0            2.0
```